# Updating an object within an array using the Strapi API generator

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, api-design, strapi

**Context:** I am creating a Nuxt PWA using Strapi for generating a REST API. At the moment I am working on creating a way of updating an array within the `user` model. The array is a ['Dynamic Zone'](https://strapi.io/blog/release-beta-18-dynamic-zones) which contains a 'component' that defines a 'one-way' relationship and a simple number value.

**Problem:** Based on the following from the Strapi [docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/content-api/api-endpoints.html#update-an-entry) I had mistakenly assumed that I could update a specific component object *within* a 'Dynamic Zone' array using the out-of-the-box `PUT` request. In the docs the `PUT` request is described as:

> Partially updates an entry by id and returns its value. Fields that aren't sent in the query are not changed in the db.

A pseudo-code of my current request is the following. What I expected this to do was update the `value` property of the component (got by `id`), within the Dynamic Zone array:

```
axios.put('baseURL/users/:id', { 
   'DynamicZoneName': [ 
      { 
        '__component: 'relationships.componentName', 
        'id': Number, 
        'value': Number 
      } 
    ] 
   }, { headers ... } 
)
```

However, while this returns a `200` OK response it deletes the rest of the 'component' objects in the array. I understand now that this is because the request takes the whole array from the key `DynamicZoneName` as `[ { '__component: 'relationships.componentName', 'id': Number, 'value': Number } ]` and updates the entire `DynamicZoneName` array to this new value.

My question is whether it would be possible to do what I originally set out to do using custom routes and controllers with Strapi. Would it *theoretically* be possible to receive the objects I wish to update at a [custom route](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/routing.html#concept) and then handle the request with a [custom controller](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html) that updates the database? (Using the received `id` to manipulate the object at `DynamicZoneName.indexOf[id]`)

Or, would it be better practice to (1) `GET` the whole array, (2) manipulate it locally in my Nuxt app and then (3) `PUT` it back using the request I've already written?

This will be an array containing 100's of objects, each of which will have at least three key-value pairs and another nested object. With this in mind I am concerned about the bandwidth of the request for both processes and (given this is my first time in PWA design) am unsure of the best practices or overall path to pursue!

At the moment, we're also looking at splitting the large `DynamicZoneName` array into multiple smaller arrays to make them more manageable for iteration over. Am more than happy to hear about other, more general methods of doing similar things if this is an architecturally poor way of constructing the API.

Comment: I am facing the issue. Please let us know if you have found the way to do this.